# How can I change legend labels in ArcGIS online?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-online

I am trying to edit a legend in ArcGIS online because the field directly from the original dataset is undescriptive. I am able to rename the layers, edit the field names of the individual points, but not the legend itself.

[Here is what the legend currently looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzZjF.png)

It is unclear what concentration is being shown or in what units. Is there a way to edit the legend label directly in ArcGIS online without the process of editing the .csv file or exporting the .zip file into ArcGIS online all over again?

Answer (score -1):

Not an intuitive fix, but I've figured it out.

Under content, click the ellipses and go to ["Configure Pop-out"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw34B.png)

Select ["Configure Attributes"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sszz6.png)

Select
["Field Alias" under desired field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG8wV.png) and add desired label

Select OK on both panels to confirm changes.

[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heR5o.png)

Again, an unintuitive solution considering you might not expect changes to pop-ups to do the same to the legend, but I hope this could help other people who might have the same issue.